# SSAS linking a date dimension to an interval columns

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following fact table :

```
ID_Activ  Date_Start   Date_End     ID_session  DayOfWeek   Time_Start  Time_End   
1         01/02/2018   15/02/2018   11          4           08:00:00    10:00:00
2         01/02/2018   15/02/2018   21          4           09:00:00    10:00:00 
3         01/03/2018   15/03/2018   31          2           09:00:00    10:00:00
```

I have a conventional dimensions date, and a custom dimension time with hours, minutes and seconds.
I would like to slice or dice using these dimensions to get this output:

```
Date        hour     Count_session
01/02/2018  08       1
01/02/2018  09       2
01/02/2018  10       2
08/02/2018  08       1
08/02/2018  09       2
08/02/2018  10       2
15/02/2018  08       1
15/02/2018  09       2
15/02/2018  10       2
06/03/2018  09       1
06/03/2018  10       1
13/03/2018  09       1
13/03/2018  10       1
```

we don't show up the null Count_session.

I tried to created a named query with all hours include in date and hours range, but it generate very lot of data!
Do you have another solution to linking a dimension with range dates ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use non empty. Your query would look like this

```
select [measures].[count_session] on 0,
non empty
([Dim Date].[Date].[Date],[Dim CustomDate].[Hour].[Hour])
on 1
from 
[YourCube]
```

Comment: Which date dimension I must use in the query, Date_star dim or Date_End dim ?

Comment: You need to expand the fact table for start and enddate each row. Your join with dimdate will be like "fact F inner join dimdate d on d.Date between F.startdate and endDate". This will give you activity count for each day.Now in your Cube make a distinct count on activityID.

Comment: As explained in my question, I already expanded fact table with dates from start and enddate of each row, but the it's very big database and it will make a lot of data, and will take a lot of time to build the cube, it's the only way ?

Comment: I am not sure that there would be anotherway.