# How to implement Between clause in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, between

I have the following fact table of events with  date and time range, I would like to select the count of Scheduled events in a specific date and DayOfweek detailed by hours, I tried to do that with Cube browser but no way, what kind of mdx query I need to use ?

```
ID_EVENT    Date_From   Date_To     ID_Schedule   DayWeek    Time_From        Time_To
1780        98-01-08    98-03-22    3420          6          10:30:00         13:00:00
1780        98-01-08    98-03-22    3422          7          09:30:00         12:00:00
1780        98-01-08    98-03-22    3423          7          09:30:00         12:00:00
1781        98-01-05    98-04-10    3424          1          15:30:00         18:00:00
1781        98-01-05    98-04-10    3430          3          18:30:00         21:00:00
1781        98-01-05    98-04-10    3431          3          19:00:00         21:15:00
1781        98-01-05    98-04-10    3432          4          15:30:00         19:00:00
1781        98-01-05    98-04-10    3433          4          15:30:00         20:00:00
1441        98-01-24    98-03-28    2909          6          09:00:00         10:30:00
1442        98-01-25    98-03-29    2910          7          09:00:00         10:30:00
1443        98-01-24    98-03-28    2911          6          10:45:00         12:15:00
1444        98-01-25    98-03-29    2912          7          10:45:00         12:15:00
```

I want to have the following Output:

```
Date       Heure   Nbr_seance
98-01-10   10:00   1
98-01-10   11:00   1
98-01-10   12:00   1
98-01-10   13:00   1
98-01-17   10:00   1
98-01-17   11:00   1
98-01-17   12:00   1
98-01-17   13:00   1
98-01-24   10:00   1
98-01-24   11:00   1
98-01-24   12:00   1
98-01-24   13:00   1
98-01-11   09:00   1
98-01-11   10:00   1
98-01-11   11:00   1
98-01-11   12:00   1
...
```

Thank you

Comment: can you please add the MDX that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
//for a particular date and day of week
select [measures].[countOfSchedule] on 0,
non empty
([Dim Date].[Date].[2019-04-09],[Dim Date].[DayOfWeek].[2],[Dim Date].[Hour].[Hour])
on 1
from 
[YourCube]

//Returns the day 2 of each week, in a date range
select [measures].[countOfSchedule] on 0,
non empty
({[Dim Date].[Date].[2019-03-01]:[Dim Date].[Date].[2019-04-01]},
[Dim Date].[DayOfWeek].[2],[Dim Date].[Hour].[Hour])
on 1
from 
[YourCube]
```

Update Sample for between clause in MDX

```
with member
 measures.startdate
as 
CDate([DimStartdate].[Date].currentmember.name)

member measures.enddate
as 
CDate([DimEnddate].[Date].currentmember.name)

select 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], measures.startdate,measures.enddate }
on columns,
filter 
(([DimStartdate].[Date].[2018/08/20]:[DimStartdate].[Date].[2018/12/20],
```

[DimEnddate].[Date].[2018/08/20]:[DimEnddate].[Date].[2018/12/20]),
    CDate("2018/9/5")> measures.startdate and CDate("2018/10/5")

Comment: Thanks @MoazRub, the facts table contain already DayofWeek, I would count only the days of  DayWeek field, I must change something in the query ?

Comment: I am sorry I could not understand your comment. Can you edit your question and add an excel pic of sample data that you want to see in the result?

Comment: question updated @MoazRub, this case has the same issue that the following one https://stackoverflow.com/q/55541818/5592285, can resolve it by returning dates and hours dynamically ?

Comment: @KiMaN the solution is same as indicated there. You have to join your startdate and enddate using between clause. Then the above query works.

Comment: Sorry @MoazRub It's not very clear for me, no need to expand dates from startdate and enddate, instead I must create two date dimensions and two time dimensions and use the above query ?

Comment: The issue is in MDX you dont have a between operator out of the box. So if you dont expand the data in the fact table the MDX query would implement the between functionality would be very complex. However I think it can be written.

Comment: The problem with the expanding is cube processing, lot of treatment and large ranges, in theory it will take more than 24h on each update ! so if you can show me the way for implementing the between clause or another solution it will be very appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191546/discussion-between-moazrub-and-kiman).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191554/discussion-between-moazrub-and-kiman).

Comment: if the above answers your problem, you should consider marking it as answer.

Comment: Sorry @MoazRub for the late reply I didn't access to the datasource server.
I m tried the MDX queries that you posted but I think it isn't the expected results. as explained in my post I would like to show the CountOfSchedule of a particular date in all ranges that match with the dayofweek of this particular date.

Comment: Hey @MoazRub, I need your help my friend, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191546/discussion-between-moazrub-and-kiman